# Git - "Poison the well" for future checkouts by employee with "stolen" code

Tags: git, security, github, version-control

Is there a way in [git](/questions/tagged/git) to "poison the well" for future checkouts? We have an employee that we will be firing in a few days due to theft of company property, and she "joked" (threatened in a less-than-joking manner) with a senior colleague about retaining a copy of company source code from our corporate GitHub repos and posting it on a torrent site to embarrass the company. She does not yet officially know that she will be fired, but likely suspects it.

Now, fortunately, our ITS team had the foresight to restrict access to a need-to-know basis, so it the code was leaked, it would be minimal (ie: no loss of significant intellectual property or trade secrets). Also, the whole interaction was recorded by security cameras, so pressing charges won't be difficult. Nevertheless, if we can reduce the potential damage to the company even further, so much the better.

By "poison the well", I mean, modify the repo she has access to (we've already backed it up), so that the next time she does a `git pull` operation, the entire local copy is effectively useless/empty. We could have done this easily enough with [subversion](/questions/tagged/subversion) by `svn rm *`, `svn commit`, done. Since `git` is distributed and local checkouts can be be reset without access to the network, this is more difficult.

Is there any `git` "magic" which a `git` admin could utilize to cause a `git pull` operation to effectively clobber a local working copy/checkout of a `git` code base?

Thank you.

Comment: Nope[.](https://git-exists-to-share-code.not.destroy.it)

Comment: @jthill Could you please elaborate, just a bit, on why it wouldn't work? I'd be grateful, as it would give me something to work with/research to have a more concrete reason in my report. Thank you. If it's written as an answer, I will also mark it "accepted".

Comment: Well, ITS saved our bacon. I just found out our VPN software allows for remote wipes of company laptops (completed just now). This is enough to satisfy our insurance policies for data breaches, and some `post-checkout` hooks to watermark a codebase to an employee, so if a tarball of the source ever ends up online, someone is facing serious jail time. Thank you SO members for your feedback.

Comment: Are you sure that she hadn't cloned the code at home? Anyway, even with your described svn way, she can checkout previous version

Comment: @Danh I agree with you, that the SVN way would not work with git (but it would with an actual SVN repo, IIRC). Anyhow, the laptop has been wiped, and her local copy of the code is apparently watermarked heavily. All our policy-related goals have been accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct answer to the question you ask is **No**. Git itself does not have the capability to delete remotely stored versions of source code based on attempted pull from a repository or other chained interaction. It would be a pretty risky capability to have and goes against the general purpose of having a distributed version control.

Im glad you found a solution to your issue elsewhere :)

Comment: Thank you. Your response is the most helpful in a technical sense. The other answer to disable employee access via blocking is also helpful. Sadly, I can only accept, not upvote.

Answer (score 1):

So it’s a private repo on github for your company? If It is. You can do some setting for it:

In the **setting** page, choose **Blocked users**, and then add her account in it. So she will has no right to access for the repo.

Comment: Will that somehow corrupt her local copy of the data, assuming she hasn't backed it up?

Comment: If the data is already exist in her local repo, it can not corrupt the data. It can only prevent her to access your github repo any more.

Comment: Thank you for this info. It's a good step to take (already been carried out by ITS).